# Animating a title in Javascript...and I'm stuck

Tags: javascript

A little background first, I just finished a "5 Day Google Maps Challenge" on Facebook, where we built a Google Maps app. That was my first real plunge into the nitty gritty of JS. While I learned a lot, here is my problem. I have a block of script that I used before--in a plug-and-play manner--but now I realize that there was more going on than simply replacing the text that I wanted to be outputted. After going through the challenge I see now that this is more of a roadmap to the effect than a plug-and-play decoration.As I said, I learned a lot, but I am at the point where I can recognize that there are things that I need to define or wrap, I'm just not totally sure how to what I need to do.

I want to apply this to the "" so, I'm guessing that I wrap that div in the "" and then move the rest of the JS to my index.js page. I know I need to define something as "title" or ".title".  I'm pretty sure something in the () of the function animate. I'm really trying to learn this, any help will be most appreciated. This was a lot easier when I wasn't aware that there were more steps that I needed to be taking. I may be over thinking this but I don't think so.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using SCSS? It offers a lot of functionality like animating the element in HTML, don't need to use JS. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp this would be a good start to see what you want specifically,

Hope it helped.

Comment: @GetSet it's in the `enter image description here` link. OP should post the code as text though.

Comment: I haven't, I'll definitely check that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I completely understand what you are trying to achieve here but I will at least explain the code that you have shown in the image. The id (effect) in the div is the unique identifier that can be given any name. 
You initialize a variable x in the script tag using the value 0.
Then you initialize the text which you want to animate in another variable named textEffect. Now you want to show the textEffect in the div (with id effect) which you have defined in your html. To do that, you grab it by using document.getElementById("effect") and assign it to the container variable. Then you want the animate function to show the text in regular intervals letter by letter so you write the if loop which says if x (that you initialized using the 0 value above) is less than the length of your statement that you want to animate (that you assigned to the textEffect variable), display the first character of the textEffect and then keep on displaying the upcoming characters one by one untill x < textEffect.length. The setTimeout function will display the character every 80 miliseconds in this case. You can change the 80 to any other number and it will change the speed accordingly. After that you write animate() outside the function to run everything that you have written above.

Comment: This is a command line style animation. I'm trying to animate the page title. Since it has a div with a class of title, I was thinking that I needed to wrap that div in the id div from the script for the effect, so I can pull that into the JS. Sorry, I didn't explain it better. As I said, I'm really just a few days into learning JS. Thanks for breaking it down for me. let me make sure I have this right. I can essentially just leave the script as is, aside from pulling the title container in from the html?

Answer (score 0):

You know what, when I saw your question I remembered a function I wrote for an mp3 web player interface, for animating the title of the song that was currently playing, in my case it was always from right to left, but since you didn't say what is the direction, I made you a select element to select the direction and even change it while moving the title, a stop button and a start button, I hope you like it, happy coding :)

```js
var element = document.querySelector("#title"),
  elementWidth = Math.floor(getComputedStyle(element).width
    .replace("px", "")),
  parentWidth = Math.floor(getComputedStyle(element.
    parentElement).width.replace("px", "")),
  movingTitle = false, lastPos = 0, direction = "left";

document.querySelector("#b_start").onclick = function() {
  movingTitle = true;
  moveTitle();
}

document.querySelector("#b_stop").onclick = function() {
  movingTitle = false;
}

document.querySelector("#b_direction").onchange = function(e) {
  direction = this.value;
};

function moveTitle() {
  var pos = lastPos;
  function move() {
    if(!movingTitle) {
      lastPos = pos;
      return;
    }
    if(direction === "right") {
      if(pos === parentWidth) {
        pos = -elementWidth;
      }else {
        pos++;
      }
      element.style.left = pos + "px";
    }else {
      if(pos === -elementWidth) {
        pos = parentWidth;
      }else {
        pos--;
      }
      element.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
    setTimeout(move, 30);
  }
  move();
}
```

```css
#title-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div id="title-container">
  <p id="title">I am a moving title.</p>
</div>
<button id="b_start">Start moving</button>
<button id="b_stop">Stop moving</button>
<label>Direction</label>
<select id="b_direction">
  <option value="left">Left</option>
  <option value="right">Right</option>
</select>
```